# How to activate Google Maps on android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I have an old java android project with simple using of google map for allocating some store locations .
the map fragment stopped working on new android version showing blank page while working on older versions like android 9 or older ..

I tried to activate the Google Map API from Google Cloud it says that I need to purchase the service
does it no longer available for free ?
and if so is there any way of activating it with out baying the service?
any help appreciated
thanks ..

Comment: Have you tried `FusedProviderClient` for Google Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps Platform is now has a pay-as-you-go billing model which means that you are charged for how many requests/map loads you make.
https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/billing

You will need to set up billing:
https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158867?hl=en

Once you've done that you can create or connect a project to the billing account:
https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started#quickstart

You can then create an API key using the steps in the link above.

You will have $200 of maps monthly credits each and every month to use before you are charged:
https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/billing#monthly-credit

Please take a look at the pricing of the SKUs here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/pricing

You can optimise your usage, set budget alerts or set daily caps on your APIs, check this optimization guide out:
https://developers.google.com/maps/optimization-guide

Don't forget to secure your API keys too:
https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices

Android SDk map loads are free unless you are loading the Maps JavaScript API or using a MapID for styling the Map:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#dynamic-maps

So, you can set daily quota limits so that you can't go over the $200 maps monthly credits and then you won't be charged for the usage, it will instead return errors.

Answer (score 1):

Google maps requires an API key and you do need to [enable billing to get one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#before-you-begin).

However there is a [monthly $200 credit](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/billing?_gl=1*ztdkhj*_ga*MjE0MDIxMjk0OC4xNjk3NTQ3OTc5*_ga_NRWSTWS78N*MTY5NzU0Nzk3OC4xLjEuMTY5NzU0Nzk5MC4wLjAuMA..#monthly-credit) for maps and Android maps are supposedly free (haven't tried personally):

> Note that the Maps Embed API, Maps SDK for Android, and Maps SDK for iOS currently have no usage limits and are at no charge (usage of the API or SDKs is not applied against your $200 monthly credit).

Source: https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

The Google map api  is free for first 5 hit.

You need to  setup  billing account to use the location api service.

For more info

https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/